# How to forward data read from a socket by prepending an IP and UDP or TCP header?

Tags: java, android

I want to forward data read from a socket. The consumer is not a socket. It expects an IP packet. Hence I have to write an IPv4 or IPv6 header. I also need to add a UDP or TCP header.

What is the best way to do this? 

I know there are big libraries (such as Jpcap?) to do this and more.

Any recommendations as to where I can find a *small* piece of java code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?  It's C# and should be easy to convert.  It's GPLed though so might not fit....

http://www.koders.com/csharp/fid9D119B4DA2575D7C03F5523345AEDB8B282EF5E4.aspx

IPv6

http://happystudy.info/jiaocheng/winsocketdotnetworkprogramming/clientserversocketnetworkcommunication8f_1a.html

Comment: Thank you. It looks promising. Think it is IPv4 only so am still looking for IPv6.

Comment: Edited.  IPv6 headers :)